# using redis giving error

Tags: node.js, redis

I have installed redis by following links .
https://github.com/mranney/node_redis

and trying

```
var redis = require("redis"),
    client = redis.createClient();

client.on("error", function (err) {
    console.log("Error " + err);
});

client.set("string key", "string val", redis.print);
client.hset("hash key", "hashtest 1", "some value", redis.print);
client.hset(["hash key", "hashtest 2", "some other value"], redis.print);
client.hkeys("hash key", function (err, replies) {
    console.log(replies.length + " replies:");
    replies.forEach(function (reply, i) {
        console.log("    " + i + ": " + reply);
    });
    client.quit();
});
```

and running `node test.js`

gives me this error why ?

```
Error Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - ECONNREFUSED, Connection refused
```

why this error is coming ? and what should i do ?

Comment: Are you sure the Redis server is running, and you did not set a password on it?

Comment: @colum yeah problem was due to redis server not starte , please update in  answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make sure the server is running before you can not access it in Node.Js

Answer (score 0):

It is worth noting that you first must install the redis server by running

sudo apt-get install redis-server

and then if it is not running you can start it by running

redis-server